# How to execute a value after dividing from two textbox value instantly in a third textbox in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a project contain master page and content page,in content page have three text boxes name.

1. `tbxTotalQuantity`
2. `tbxTotalPrice` and
3. `tbxPricePerItem`.

I want to appear `pricePerItem` on third textbox (`tbxPricePerItem`) after typing textbox (1) and (2). I'm trying to write code according to complete work but it does not work.

```
 <div class="panel-body">
         <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Quantity</h6>
         <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalQuantity" CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="setPrice();"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Total Price</h6>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTotalPrice"  CssClass="form-control" onkeyup="setPrice();" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h6>&nbsp;&nbsp;Price/Item</h6>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPricePerItem" CssClass="form-control"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function setPrice() {
            var totalQuantity = document.getElementById('tbxTotalQuantity').value;           
            var totalPrice = document.getElementById('tbxTotalPrice').value;          
            var result = parseInt(totalPrice) / parseInt(totalQuantity);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('tbxPricePerItem').value = result;
              
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: what issue you are getting ?

Comment: I think JS wouldn't find any of textboxes by they id because they are in conent page. If they are in content page, ids got prefixes. Try to see Page source in browser and you'll see complete ids.

Comment: and your script on master page ?

Comment: see your browser console and find what error you have ?

Comment: @SunilKumar what about script in master page?? for this problem is irrelevant where script is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the above problem is taking help of the ASP.Net Inline Tags and the ClientID and UniqueID properties of an ASP.Net Control. The definition of the both the terms is given below

**ClientID –** ASP.NET automatically generates a ClientID for a server when the control is rendered as HTML id of the control

**UniqueID –** The hierarchically-qualified unique identifier assigned to a control by the ASP.NET rendered as HTML name of the control

So you can try below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function setPrice() {
            var totalQuantity = document.getElementById("<%=tbxTotalQuantity.ClientID%>").value;           
            var totalPrice = document.getElementById("<%=tbxTotalPrice.ClientID%>").value;          
            var result = parseInt(totalPrice) / parseInt(totalQuantity);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById("<%=tbxPricePerItem.ClientID%>").value = result;

            }
        }
    </script>
```

Hope it will help you.

Thanks